# C# Serialization - Class having List of other class

Tags: c#, serialization

i have some problem with serialization. Let's say i have class like this:

```
Class Hardware
{
public string cpu_name;
public int ram_size;
List<HardDisk> hd;
Class HardDisk{ public string model; public int size;}
}
```

What is the simpliest way to get result as:

```
<HardwareInfo>
<cpu_name> ABC Pentium xyz</cpu_name>
<ram_size> 123 </ram_size>
<hard_disk> 
<model>Toshiba XYZ</model>
<size> 123 GB </size>
</hard_disk>
<hard_disk> 
<model>Logitech XYZ</model>
<size> 99 GB </size>
</hard_disk>
</HardwareInfo>
```

I have generated my own metod just to add tags, and it looks like i have written, but i will also have to write my "deserialization" method if i use this...

so can you please tell me how to simply serialize in XML this?

p.s. 
i have read some question similiar to mine, but i didnt understand too much. my english is not too good :(

Comment: Well, your HardDisk class needs to be serializable as well.  What have you tried?

Comment: that doesn't look like valid c#. `Class` should be `class` I believe.  Additionally, serialization, via any library I've ever seen, works only on properties, not fields.

Comment: @SharkyShark, does the answer met your needs? If so, please, mark it. If not, tell us your difficulties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some issues if you are using C#. I have made some corretions and included some assembly information to get the result you expect. See code below.

Here is how your classes should be:

```
[System.Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "hard_disk")]
public class HardDisk
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public string model { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public int size { get; set; }

    public HardDisk() { }
}


[System.Serializable]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot(ElementName = "HardwareInfo")]
public class Hardware
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public string cpu_name { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public int ram_size { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "hard_disk")]
    public List<HardDisk> hd { get; set; }

    public Hardware()
    {
        hd = new List<HardDisk>();
    }
}
```

The code to serialize using your expected result as example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hw = new Hardware()
        {
            cpu_name = "ABC Pentium xyz",
            ram_size = 123,
            hd = new List<HardDisk>()
            {
                new HardDisk() {
                    model = "Toshiba XYZ",
                    size = 123
                },
                new HardDisk() {
                    model = "Logitech XYZ",
                    size = 99
                }
            }
        };

        var xml = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Hardware));

        var ns = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        xml.Serialize(Console.Out, hw, ns);
    }
}
```

Your result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<HardwareInfo>
  <cpu_name>ABC Pentium xyz</cpu_name>
  <ram_size>123</ram_size>
  <hard_disk>
    <model>Toshiba XYZ</model>
    <size>123</size>
  </hard_disk>
  <hard_disk>
    <model>Logitech XYZ</model>
    <size>99</size>
  </hard_disk>
</HardwareInfo>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be use this sample code

Importent Note

- Serialized `class` mark as `[Serializable]` attirbute
- If the class name is not same as the xml root tag, class will be mark as `[XmlRoot(ElementName = "XmlTagName")]` attribute
- If serialized class have property type as another class, this property mark as `[XmlElement("XmlTagName")]` attribute

> you can check the [article](http://bilisim.io/2017/02/11/net-serialization-deserialization/) for `Serialization & Deserialization`

**Model**

```
            [Serializable]
            [XmlRoot(ElementName = "HardwareInfo")]
            public class Hardware
            {
                [XmlElement]
                public string cpu_name { get; set; }
                [XmlElement]
                public int ram_size { get; set; }

                [XmlElement("hard_disk")]
                public List<HardDisk> hd { get; set; }                   
            }

            [Serializable]
            [XmlRoot(ElementName = "hard_disk")]
            public class HardDisk
            {
                [XmlElement]
                public string model { get; set; }
                [XmlElement]
                public string size { get; set; }
            }

    namespace ConsoleApplication1
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string xmlString = @"<HardwareInfo>
                                      <cpu_name> ABC Pentium xyz</cpu_name>
                                      <ram_size> 123 </ram_size>
                                      <hard_disk>
                                        <model>Toshiba XYZ</model>
                                        <size> 123 GB </size>
                                      </hard_disk>
                                      <hard_disk>
                                        <model>Logitech XYZ</model>
                                        <size> 99 GB </size>
                                      </hard_disk>
                                    </HardwareInfo>";

                var result = DeSerialization<Hardware>(xmlString);
            }

            static T DeSerialization<T>(string xmlStrig) where T : class
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));                        
                using (StringReader sReader = new StringReader(xmlStrig))
                {
                    return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sReader);
                }
            }
        }          
    }
```